# Why doesn't Java's main use a variable length argument list?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, variadic-functions

I have a question about the syntax of the Java `main` declaration:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

Since you can pass a variable number of Strings when invoking the main function, shouldn't this be a variable length argument list rather than an array? Why would a command-line invocation of this method with a list of string parameters even work? (Unless there is behind-the-scenes processing that builds an array with the list of strings and then passes that array to the main method...?) Shouldn't the main declaration be something more like this...? -

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a backwards compatibility concern...

Comment: I don't really think that you should be calling the main function yourself... It is meant to be called from the VM.

Comment: I don't call the main function myself. I didn't think it was possible. I guess this was really a question about the inner workings of Java...

Comment: Many people are saying "you never call main from code".  That isn't true, it just rare.  Usually I'd see main being invoked from code in a plugin/runtime loading scenario, similar to how jUnit loads new code at runtime.  (FYI I am making a big assumption here that jUnit works like NUnit.  Java sounds cool, but I've only used C# :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers and comments! This question has been bothering me since I first learned about variable length argument lists and I appreciate that you've all helped me understand it.

Comment: One last question based on what you've all said: so a method with a "String[] arg" and a method with a "String... arg" parameter are considered the same declaration/method header by Java? Does this mean that you wouldn't be able to overload them - say, have a "public void someMethod(String[] arg)" method and a "public void someMethod(String... arg)" method because Java would have no way of differentiating between them?

Comment: @froadie: Yes, that's the same method signature, so declaring both will result in a "Duplicate methode" compiler error.

Comment: Even Oracle uses `String... args` here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`main(String... args)` and `main (String[] args)` are effectively the same thing: What you're getting is a `String` array. The varargs is just syntactic sugar for the caller.

I guess as you never call `main()` from code, it wasn't retrofitted when varargs were introduced.

*Edit*: Actually, scratch that last sentence. `main(String... args)` is perfectly valid syntax, of course. The two styles are completely interchangeable. This works just fine:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Comment: So when you execute a program from command line, you're not actually directly calling the main? There's some processing that occurs before the main is executed? (i.e. building the array from the strings passed)

Comment: They are not same. One cannot call `main (String[] args)` as `main("aaaa")`.

Comment: You're not invoking the main() method using Java. The runtime invokes it for you.

Comment: "never call main() FROM CODE" :). And no. You cannot call a Java method from a command line. In fact a command line is a program that parse your command, tells the OS to execute some program with a bunch of args, and that program (java.exe by example) load a lot of things into memory (class definitions, etc), creates a Java friendly representation of the system program execution args the command line received, and finally calls the main method. So... no. You're not actually directly calling the main.

Comment: re: "never call main() from code" - CAN you call main from code??

Comment: I don't have much of an opinion on calling main from code--it doesn't seem like something you'd want to do much, but in certain situations it should be perfectly valid (for instance, causing one program to run either from within another or as it's own entity).  @helios do you have real life experience or even theoritical examples where this was a problem?

Comment: Of course you can call "main" from code, and it may make perfect sense to do so. Consider for example a Java utility to invoke "main" in a series of one or more classes. How would you write that? Another example is in writing Ant tasks that glue onto existing Java (command-line) utilities.

Comment: @Bill K: I was just quoting part of the answer. @froadie made his first comment and a pointed at that part of the answer. It was like "Henning said 'FROM CODE'". Next part was: command line is related to main execution of course but it's not a Java method call so it will be related and designed to mimic each other but it doesn't have to have a particular form.

Answer (score 16):

You can declare main either way, and it works just fine.  There are no "backward compatibility" or "retrofitting" issues.  However, readers of your code may find it distracting, and it is unlikely to improve your program in any way.

[The Java Language Specification (third edition) section 8.4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.1) says that "If the last formal parameter is a variable arity parameter of type *T*, it is considered to define a formal parameter of type *T[]*".

The specification for how a Java program starts up is in [JLS 12.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.1), which references chapter 5 of the VM spec.  The [VM spec section 5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html#51579) says that the VM invokes a public class method "`void main(String[])`".  Since the VM spec has no concept of variable arity, a main that was declared using "`...`" satisfies the requirement.

Answer (score 9):

The main method was designed for Java 1.0.

The "..." syntax was introduced in Java 1.5

It's implemented via an array of the type you defined (my guess, but... if Java 1.4 and 1.5 byte codes are compatible so it must be implemented with arrays).

Answer (score 6):

There is no *Java's main method*, in fact you can declare the array as a vararg in *your main method*:

```
public static void main(String... args) { System.out.println("Hi!"); }
```

Comment: Interesting. Judging by the other answers/comments, I guess this new main declaration syntax was added with Java 1.5. So the Java runtime determines, based on your main method declaration, whether to pass the strings directly to the main or build an array first?

Comment: Varargs were introduced in Java 5 as syntactic sugar for arrays, meaning they hide the actual array, but underneath, it is the same thing, which is why this works. See also http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: No. It always builds an array. It's just a different syntax for expressing the exact same underlying code. Java will still parse the command line args into a string array, load the referenced class, find it's main method, and call it with the args.

Comment: @froadie: No, it always builds an array. `String... args` == `String[] args`, as far as the called method is concerned. The parameter is an array in any case.

Answer (score 1):

The java main syntax predates varargs, which were only introduced in java 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

> *Shouldn't the main declaration be something more like this...?*

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Actually, that could be done without a problem.

It was `String [] args` before var args were introduced but nowadays both work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the 2nd syntax is just a variation of 1st and yes it would be nice but it's not built into Java at this point