# why method varargs must be in separate block in java?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Why method varargs must be in separate from main method body? Below code is correct, but why can't I put varargs method declaration in the main method body?

```
public class TryVariableArgumentList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x("first","second");

        public static void x(String... list) {
            for (String y : list)
                System.out.println(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Java's main use a variable length argument list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201696/why-doesnt-javas-main-use-a-variable-length-argument-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the method

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    //code
}
```

is also perfectly legal

The problem with the code is Method declaration inside a method itself is not allowed in Java

Compilable code has to be like this

```
class TryVariableArgumentList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x("first","second");
    }

    public static void x(String... list) {
        for(String y : list)
            System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

I think you need to post what you read,because maybe you have interpreted something incorrectly

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you , i changed my code ,can you tell me why it's not compiled?

Comment: Method inside a method is not allowed in Java

Comment: Edited my answer tooo

Answer (score 0):

Your method x is declared in method main. This is not legal. Declare x outside of main.