# Java 8 varargs on main function signature

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I was converting a Groovy codebase into Java and *forgot* to change

```
public static void main(String... args) {
```

to

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

and compiled and ran the project all this time only to be surprised *only now* that this is legal Java 8 code.

I understand that [Java 8 Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) makes it possible for a function to have arbitrary number of arguments, "compacting them into an Array" depending on their position on the method call.

But the way functions with `String... args` and `String[] args` are called syntactically differently:

```
void function1 (String[] args) {}
function1({"one", "two", "three"});

void function2 (String... args) {}
function2("one", "two", "three");
```

So how is `String... args` as legal as `String args[]` when grabbing params from the terminal?

---

**Edit:**

[azurefrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361506/azurefrog) linked an answer to a different question that is great. I wanted to mention another answer where the comments provide the answer I was looking for:

[Why doesn't Java's main use a variable length argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201696/why-doesnt-javas-main-use-a-variable-length-argument-list/2201895#2201895)

Comment 1: Interesting. Judging by the other answers/comments, I guess this new main declaration syntax was added with Java 1.5. So the Java runtime determines, based on your main method declaration, whether to pass the strings directly to the main or build an array first?

Comment 2: No, it always builds an array. `String... args == String[]` args, as far as the called method is concerned. The parameter is an array in any case

That's the question I had. Sorry if it was asked poorly.

Comment: Basically, because the JLS says so.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2201895/1361506).

Comment: varargs is valid in Java since 1.5 I guess. Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301563/difference-fnstring-args-vs-fnstring-args

Comment: @Wizard not a duplicate. I'm not asking what one syntax is good for versus the other. I'm asking about the underlying implementation of running Java code with the same result when you use either syntaxes.

Comment: From now on I'm calling them "vargars".  Sounds cool.

Comment: This is a very beginner level question. Maybe I asked it poorly. IF you down vote, please tell me why or edit the question. That helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regarding the downvotes: you're presuming this behavior is an unusual (or new) feature, neither of which is true. If you remove that presumption your question simply becomes "why can I use varargs in `main()`?", and the answer is just "because the JLS says so", which isn't a very valuable question/answer. I didn't downvote, just providing feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been legal since varargs were added to the language, I believe.  The syntax for calling them explicitly differs, sure, but command-line arguments are passed in not by other Java code but "magically."

[JLS 12.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) specifies this:

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> public static void main(String... args)
> ```

Comment: I was under the impression that `javaCode arg1 arg2` would turn the parameters into one array. Thus I thought the other way to define main would be with param `String[]... args` so it could take an arbitrary number of `String[]`. But I'm starting to understand the basic difference between running Java code (after compiled) and calling Java code (from other code).

Comment: Where do you think the second dimension would come from?  `String[]...` has the same type as `String[][]`.

Comment: That what I thought. Your answer provided enough light for me to identify the flaw on my thinking. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As you already said, at **compile-time** all varargs`...` are swapped out with arrays`[]`.

Thus the java compiler recognizes your vararg parameters and puts them into an array.

See @Louis_Wasserman 's answer for the JSL quote.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html --- the Java Tutorial